# Apache camel xpath conditional routing

Tags: java, xpath, soap, apache-camel, cxf

I have a camel route in my application context defined as

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    trace="true" id="camel">

    <route id="wsProxyRedirection">
        <from uri="cxf:bean:cdcPocProxyWebServiceStartPoint" />
        <choice>
            <when>
                <xpath>//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/hel:sayHello/toWhom = 'normal'</xpath>
                <to uri="jms:queue:normalQueue" />
            </when>
            <when>
                <xpath>//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/hel:sayHello/toWhom = 'urgent'</xpath>
                <to uri="jms:queue:urgentQueue" />
            </when>
            <when>
                <xpath>//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/hel:sayHello/toWhom = 'veryUrgent'</xpath>
                <to uri="jms:queue:veryUrgentQueue" />
            </when>
        </choice>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

The request that I send is:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:hel="http://cxf.apache.org/wsse/handler/helloworld">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <hel:sayHello>
         <toWhom>normal</toWhom>
      </hel:sayHello>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But the response I get is:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Error during type conversion from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.w3c.dom.Document with value test due org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

It is just a simple choice POC, but I cannot make it works... What do I have to change in my xpath condition?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example seems right. Question is how you send message, cause data received by cxf was not valid for xml, so you receive SAXParseException.
Of course you shouldn't use "${simple} contains", cause you working with xml, and apache camel provide a lot of instruments to work with it. 
I create test example by your requirements.

Cxf endpoint:

```
<camelcxf:cxfEndpoint
        id="cdcPocProxyWebServiceStartPoint"
        wsdlURL="etc/Test.WSDL"
        address="/services/request">
    <camelcxf:properties>
        <entry key="dataFormat" value="PAYLOAD"/>
    </camelcxf:properties>
</camelcxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

When you using payload dataformat you will work exactly with soap:Body content and u needn't using SOAP tags in xpath.

Route:

```
<camelContext id="incomingRequestsProcessing" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="wsProxyRedirection" xmlns:hel="http://cxf.apache.org/wsse/handler/helloworld">
        <from uri="cxf:bean:cdcPocProxyWebServiceStartPoint?loggingFeatureEnabled=true"/>
        <choice>
            <when>
                <xpath>//hel:sayHello/toWhom = 'normal'</xpath>
                <log message="Receive average hello status"/>
            </when>
            <when>
                <xpath>//hel:sayHello/toWhom = 'urgent'</xpath>
                <log message="Receive urgent hello status"/>
            </when>
            <when>
                <xpath>//hel:sayHello/toWhom = 'veryUrgent'</xpath>
                <log message="Receive very urgent hello status"/>
            </when>
        </choice>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

I using SoapUI for testing. And result of sending your request is:

```
2017-10-13 17:19:37,745 | INFO  | tp1048175215-590 | wsProxyRedirection               | 178 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.16.3 | Receive average hello status
```

I tried to set big part of logs but i could not. Editor says that "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code". Sadly i don't know how to do this.
Hope my post will help you.

Answer (score 1):

It worked when changing `<xpath>//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/hel:sayHello/toWhom = 'normal'</xpath>` with `<simple>${body} contains 'normal'</simple>`

But I would like to make it works with xpath..

Answer (score 0):

In "when" condition, instead of "xpath", try using "simple". replace these words.

< xpath> -> < simple>

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a different `dataFormat` parameter to the consumer endpoint. Try with `CXF_MESSAGE`:

```
<from uri="cxf:bean:cdcPocProxyWebServiceStartPoint?dataFormat=CXF_MESSAGE" />
```

Also, try to change your `<xpath ... />` to use the following format:

`<xpath>//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/hel:sayHello[toWhom='normal']</xpath>`

Comment: Does anything change if you set the `dataFormat` to `MESSAGE`?

Comment: The message is not consumed and I got a timeout error

Comment: Try to add `?exchangePattern=InOnly` parameter to the jms endpoints. (eg. `<to uri="jms:queue:normalQueue?exchangePattern=InOnly" />`.

Comment: same problem, and I tried with `PAYLOAD` data format (cause `MESSAGE` is deprecated). I get a response with that (no more timeout) but, I cannot make the conditionnal choice (the field is not extracted).

Comment: In case of `PAYLOAD`, try to change the xpath to `/hel:sayHello[toWhom='normal']`, because the content of the body is the soap:Body! (http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html#CXF-Thedescriptionsofthedataformats)

Comment: I meant `RAW`, sorry.
So I tried with `PAYLOAD` but got `org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Byte cannot be cast to java.lang.String` (with the modification of the condition as you mentionned)